# Is there a way to append a function with arguments into a list?

Tags: python, list, function, arguments, append

I have created a loop that runs functions out of a list.

At the end of each function I run, I append the next function that I would need to run into this list.

This is how I append them into the list:

```
self.FunctionBuffer["stack"].append( self.ApplyFunction )
```

This is how I call them:

```
if len(self.FunctionBuffer["stack"]) > 0:
    self.FunctionBuffer["stack"][0]()
```

Everything had been working well except now I want to add arguments to the functions I append and there doesn't seem to be a syntax for this such as:

```
self.FunctionBuffer["stack"].append( self.ApplyFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3) )
```

Is there a way I can append a function with arguments into a list?

Comment: What language? Python?

Comment: To clarify, you want to call `self.ApplyFunction()` multiple times, using a different parameter each time?

Comment: What if you append a list with the function and its arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a *new* callable that'll call your function with arguments:

```
from functools import partial

self.FunctionBuffer["stack"].append(partial(self.ApplyFunction, arg1, arg2, arg3))
```

`functools.partial` stores your function and your arguments, and when you call the partial object returned, it in turn will invoke the function with those arguments. You can add *extra* arguments when calling that object too:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def foo(bar, baz): print (bar, baz)
... 
>>> p = partial(foo, 1, 2)
>>> p()
(1, 2)
>>> p = partial(foo, 1)
>>> p(2)
(1, 2)
```

You can achieve the same thing with lambdas:

```
self.FunctionBuffer["stack"].append(lambda: self.ApplyFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3))
```

but a `partial()` is faster and provides the option to pass in more arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just shove a list containing your arguments into the second element of the list you're appending to `FunctionBuffer`?

```
self.FunctionBuffer["stack"].append([self.ApplyFunction,[arg1, arg2, arg3]])

...

if len(self.FunctionBuffer["stack"]) > 0:
    self.FunctionBuffer["stack"][0][0](*self.FunctionBuffer["stack"][0][1])
```